# Что актуально для фриланса (и будет актуально еще длительное время)

Tags: python-3.x

**TL; DR: Чем можно *стабильно* заниматься на удаленке, получая достойные деньги, не считая веб-программирования?**

Полноценно учиться программированию я еще не начал, но перед этим нужно выбрать направление, сферу. В будущем я хочу работать исключительно как фрилансер (не считая первых нескольких лет, чтобы набраться опыта) и зарабатывать достаточно для хорошей жизни, путешествий етс, также в будущем хочу эмигрировать из Украины.

Главный вопрос, который я хочу задать -- что еще актуально кроме веб-программирования, с достойной зарплатой? С математикой у меня хорошо, даже очень, но какая-нибудь исследовательская работа меня не сильно привлекает, потому что главным приоритетом является заработок. Уже программировал на Пайтоне, сильно понравилось (решал конкретную математическую задачу), я чувствую, что это мое и смогу хорошо заниматься этим делом. Можно ли заниматься низкоуровневым программированием на удаленке (понятно, что можно, я имею в виду, насколько это реально и какой там будет заработок)?

В данный момент мне (почти) 16 лет, готовлюсь к поступлению через год в какой-нибудь университет (во-первых, для базы, во-вторых, как социальный лифт, да и вообще я не в Киеве живу, там найти работу будет легче).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если с математикой хорошо, то развивайтесь в Data Science. Зарплата достойная, зачастую даже переплачивают, т.к. область еще молодая и специалистов слишком мало, чтобы удовлетворить спрос. Порог входа высок, нужно знать матан. Теоретические исследования здесь идут постоянно, но и чистого кода тут пишут тоже немало. [Статейка](https://habr.com/company/newprolab/blog/419117/) тут недавно как раз вышла, если интересно, почитайте.
Насчет удаленки в низкоуровневом программировании могу сказать только то, что чем ниже будет уровень языка, тем сложнее будет найти удаленные вакансии, почти все идут в веб или в мобильную разработку. Допустим,работа с микроконтроллерами и другим промышленным железом почти исключает удаленку, а если и есть, то нужен большой опыт.
Ну и последнее - очень сильно помогает опыт участия в опенсорсе, таким людям вообще все двери открыты (можно вполне прокачиваться в этом направлении во время учебы в универе).

Comment: Да, очень интересно, такой еще вопрос: для Data Science логичнее будет пойти на какую-нибудь "Прикладную математику" для линейной алгебры, теории вероятности, матана, статистики (ведь школьной программы мне очевидно не хватит) или на что-нибудь связанное с программированием ("Инженерия программного обеспечения")?

Comment: Вообще, любые знания можно приобрести и самому при желании, на той "Инженерии..." в том же КНУ, как мне кажется, будет больше вероятность скоро начать работать, приобретать опыт в программировании, а в "Прикладной математике" я слишком боюсь возвращения школьной атмосферы.

Comment: Да, тут либо Прикладная математика, либо Бизнес информатика. Второе сильно приближено к чистому data science, во время обучения нужно конечно же самому дополнительные знания приобретать. Вообще есть куча курсов и готовых планов по этому направлению (к примеру https://proglib.io/p/learn-data/). Ну и вуз смотрите нормальный, чтобы 4 года просто так не прошло (в этом случае первые 2 курса свободное время только на программу универа будет уходить).

Comment: Вот здесь еще разъясняют подробно - https://rb.ru/opinion/data-rules/